# Showing Form from a thread not rendering perfectly

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, thread-safety, xmpp

I am developing a chat application using jabber-net opensource library.. 
my aim is to display a form (chat window ) when a message is coming.
But when I use this code, Form appears in the task bar,,, not perfectly rendered... 
seems like this... More over I can see the form only when I mousehover the Icon on taskbar (Hail Windows 7)... Any form are like this...

[Click here for Output Image](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-mfV1D8UHHis/UoyMvpA6KVI/AAAAAAAAAFs/PhDhcL_lNw0/w291-h342-no/Untitled.png)

my code is this...

```
    public jabber.client.JabberClient jabberClient1;
    jabberClient1.User = UserName;
    jabberClient1.Password = Password;
    jabberClient1.Resource = resource;
    jabberClient1.AutoRoster = true;
    jabberClient1.OnMessage += new MessageHandler(jabberClient1_OnMessage);

    private void jabberClient1_OnMessage(object sender, jabber.protocol.client.Message msg)
    {
        try
        {
            chatWindow chw = new chatWindow();
            chw.Left = 0;
            chw.Top = 0;
            chw.TopMost = true;
            //chw.LoadChat(msg.From.User, msg.From.Bare, "0");
            //chw.SetMessage(msg);
            chw.Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Redirect this action to main application thread using `Control.BeginInvoke` or `Control.Invoke` method. `jabberClient1_OnMessage` is probably called in arbitrary thread context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it myself... 
I have to use

```
JabberClient1.InvokeControl = FormInstance;
```

and, the FormInstance should be shown Before the chat window appears.... 
ie, It can be the contact window (Roster)....

Answer (score 1):

you have to use chw.ShowDialog()

or use if invokerequired

```
    private delegate void dlgInvokeRequired();

public void InvokeMethode()
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired == true) 
    {
     dlgInvokeRequired d = new dlgInvokeRequired(InvokeMethode);
     this.Invoke(d);
    } else 
    {
     chatWindow chw = new chatWindow();
     chw.Left = 0;
     chw.Top = 0;
     chw.TopMost = true;
     //chw.LoadChat(msg.From.User, msg.From.Bare, "0");
     //chw.SetMessage(msg);
     chw.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: It wont work.... I have solved it myself...
I have to use JabberClient1.InvokeControl = FormInstance; 
and, the FormInstance should be shown Before the chat window appears.... ie, It can be the contact window....